# Magento 2. how to hide 'Add to cart button' using Plugins

Tags: magento2, frontend, addtocart

How to Hide 'Add to cart' button using Plugins.I'm stuck in to hide add to cart button.

Comment: check the following link to know more about "how to disable add to cart button via override", https://magenticians.com/magento-2-disable-add-to-cart-button/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using you can `hide add to cart button` for all cases.

At somecases, you **need to use plugin. Like product details page**

But some other cases like Product listing page like ***Category or Catalog search  page Or Crossell and Upsell products*** you have to  hide *add to Cart Button* by ***removing the code from phtml*** .

Answer (score -1):

You can hide it via css too.

```
.box-tocart{
display:none;
}
```